# Property depending on another property, get erroring

Tags: c#, properties

This is the situation, I have a class with two properties. If Sex is null, then it gets set depending on the value of SexString, the problem is accessing the value of Sex, it errors when I try to access it. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Person

public string SexString { get; set; }

public int? Sex 
{
    get { return this.Sex.Value; }
    set 
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            if (this.SexString.Trim().ToLower() == "female") 
            {
                this.Sex = 1; 
            }
            else if (this.SexString.Trim().ToLower() == "male") 
            { 
                this.Sex = 0; 
            }
            else 
            { 
                this.Sex = 3; 
            }
        }
        else if (value <= 3 && value >= 0) 
        {
            this.Sex = value; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            this.Sex = 3; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `return this.Sex.Value;` causes *stack overflow*: `this.Sex` calls `this.Sex` which call `this.Sex` etc. Use *backing field* (say, `int? m_Sex`) to break this vicious circle of calls

Answer (score 3):

You have *Stack Overflow* problem: whenever you call

```
this.Sex
```

within `Sex` property it starts to call `Sex` property which calls `this.Sex` which calls `Sex` etc.
Try using *backing field*:

```
private int? m_Sex;

public int? Sex {
  get => m_Sex.HasValue ? m_Sex.Value : 3;
  set {
    if (value == null) 
      if ("female".Equals(SexString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        m_Sex = 1;
      else if ("male".Equals(SexString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        m_Sex = 2; //TODO: check this value: is it 0 or 2?
      else
        m_Sex = 3;
    else if (value >= 0 && value <= 3)
      m_Sex = value;
    else
      m_Sex = 3; 
  } 
}
```

**Side note:** Have a look at [ISO/IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218) - *standard* sex codes:

- 0 = Not known
- 1 = Male
- 2 = Female
- 9 = Not applicable

May be you should not invent your own codes? If you stick to standard you can easily implement `Sex` property:

```
private int m_Sex;

public int Sex {
  get => m_Sex;
  set {
    m_Sex = value >= 0 && value <= 2 || value == 9
      ? value
      : throw new ArgumentOutOfRange(nameof(value)); 
  }
}
```

As for `SexString`, you can derive it from `m_Sex`:

```
public string SexString {
  get => m_Sex == 0 ? "Unknown"
       : m_Sex == 1 ? "Male"
       : m_Sex == 2 ? "Female"
       : "Not applicable";
  set {
    if ("unknown".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
        "not known".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
        "?".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      m_Sex = 0;
    else if ("male".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             "man".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             "m".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      m_Sex = 1;
    else if ("female".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             "woman".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             "w".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             "f".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      m_Sex = 2;
    else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ||
             "-".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             "Not applicable".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      m_Sex = 9;
    else
      throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid sex definition", nameof(value));   
  }
}
```